# My computer can not boot after the partition

Tags: windows-7, boot-partition

when i try to partition the C drive on my laptop using an application, and I managed to partition, then I restarted again, and this is where the problem arises, my laptop can not boot to get into windows, what happened? if anyone can have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your [BCD Entries](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/bcd-stores.html) were erased and are missing...

Boot [WINPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) on your machine or even a Windows DVD instalation and go to the command screen provided on the "open command promt"(or something like this) on advanced instalation options and run the following command:

```
bcdboot c:\Windows
```

Also, look [this reference](http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/Kmadhav/blog/4343-How-to-Solve-BCD-Corruption-in-Windows-7/) if having problems on this procedure.

This will create your BCD Entries again.

Comment: Alternatively, the auto-startup-repair facility on the Windows 7 Installer disk is pretty good at automatically finding and fixing BCD-related problems, so long as the partition containing your OS install is readable.

Comment: Good point, it is basically the same thing.